# Cumulative sum by row

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

For the following data set

```
data example;
input x y;
cards;
1 8
2 7
3 6
4 5
;
run;
```

I would like to create a new data set that has the following column added:

```
sum 
10 
9 
7 
4
```

10 comes from summing the first column (1+2+3+4), 9 comes from (2+3+4), and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a correlated aggregate subquery in with `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    create table cumsum as
    (select sup.x, sup.y,
          (select sum(sub.x) from example as sub where sub.x >= sup.x) as sum 
     from example as sup);
quit;

x   y   sum
1   8   10
2   7   9
3   6   7
4   5   4
```

Alternatively, you can run a cumulative sum via a data step. Since you need a decreasing cumulative sum, sorting prior and after is needed:

```
proc sort data=example out=example;
    by descending x;
run;

data cumsum2;
  set example;
  if first.x then sum = 0;
  sum + x;    
run;

proc sort data=cumsum2 out=cumsum2;
    by x;
run;

x   y   sum
1   8   10
2   7   9
3   6   7
4   5   4
```